# Are there alternative solution without cross-join in Spark 2?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Stackoverflow!

I wonder if there is a fancy way in Spark 2.0 to solve the situation below.
The situation is like this.

Dataset1 (TargetData) has this schema and has about 20 milion records.

- id (String)
- vector of embedding result (Array, 300 dim)

Dataset2 (DictionaryData) has this schema and has about 9,000 records.

- dict key (String)
- vector of embedding result (Array, 300 dim)

For each vector of records in dataset 1, I want to find the dict key that will be the maximum when I compute cosine similarity it with dataset 2.

Initially, I tried cross-join dataset1 and dataset2 and calculate cosine simliarity of all records, but the amount of data is too large to be available in my environment.

I have not tried it yet, but I thought of collecting dataset2 as a list and then applying udf.

Are there any other method in this situation?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be two options the one is to [broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) Dataset2 since you need to scan it for each row of Dataset1 thus avoid the network delays by accessing it from a different node. Of course in this case you need to consider first if your cluster can handle the memory cost which 9000rows x 300cols(not too big in my opinion). Also you still need your join although with broadcasting should be faster. The other option is to populate a  [RowMatrix](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html) from your existing vectors and leave spark do the calculations for you

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a question. In the first solution, you mean that before cross-join I need to broadcast dataset2? Is it true that I interpreted it correctly?.

Comment: Yes exactly you can try the broadcast before the join